# OpsCenter seems to not read configuration file

Tags: opscenter

I have just installed OpsCenter 5.0, using "DataStax All-in-One Installer" on Linux.

I have tried to add authentication by setting the following in `/etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf`:

```
[authentication]
enabled = True
```

After restarting the server `service opscenterd restart` the authentication is still not present.

I have tried to enable SSL using the documentation instructions and got no effects as well. The server even does not listen on the 8443 port which was set by default.

After analysis of the log file `/var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log` I have not found any related errors.

What came to my mind, is that OpsCenter may be not reading the configuration file? To check that, I have decided to put some random string to the configuration file to induce an error during OpsCenter daemon start. After restart the log file was still free of related errors.

My another thought was that maybe OpsCenter simply omits invalid strings? I have removed the previously invalid string and edited the `port` value to `8887` in the `[webserver]` section. After restart OpsCenter was still listening under 8888, without having binded to 8887.

My last try was to reboot the entire server. It didn't help as well.

It all looks like OpsCenter simply does not read the configuration file. What can causing this? How can I fix this?

Thank you for your time,
Adam

PS:
Here is the entire `/var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log` content. I am provoding also a [PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/4c7LVWUP) for better readibility.

```
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Log opened.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: twistd 10.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.7 2.7.6) starting up.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: set uid/gid 0/0
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Logging level set to 'info'
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: OpsCenter version: 5.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Compatible agent version: 5.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Loading per-cluster config file ./conf/clusters/local.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: HTTP BASIC authentication disabled
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Starting webserver with ssl disabled.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Stats Reporter is connected via HTTP
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: SSL disabled
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [] ERROR: Unable to import SSL, further definition actions will fail.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Starting Definition Update Service
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer starting on 8888
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer instance at 0x7fe23a2ac128>
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: morbid.morbid.StompFactory starting on 61619
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Starting factory <morbid.morbid.StompFactory instance at 0x7fe237a41368>
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Configuring agent communication with ssl support disabled.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: morbid.morbid.StompFactory starting on 61620
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [] ERROR: No http agent exists, likely due to SSL import failure.
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Starting services for cluster local
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugins
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading event plugins
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Metric caching enabled with 50 points and 1000 metrics cached
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Starting PushService
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: Starting CassandraCluster service
2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [local]  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra/system.log', 'thrift_port': 9160, 'jmx_pass': '*****', 'thrift_ssl_truststore': None, 'rollups86400_ttl': -1, 'api_port': '61621', 'use_ssl': 0, 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'kerberos_debug': False, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'thrift_user': '', 'provisioning': 0, 'metrics_ignored_column_families': '', 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter', 'jmx_user': '', 'cassandra_install_location': '', 'kerberos_use_keytab': True, 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'thrift_pass': '*****', 'metrics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'metrics_enabled': 1, 'kerberos_use_ticket_cache': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_type': 'JKS', 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'kerberos_renew_tgt': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_password': '*****'}
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 []  INFO: OS Version: Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 []  INFO: CPU Info: ['2666.774', '2666.774']
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 []  INFO: Mem Info: 2989MB
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Enterprise functionality: True
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Cluster Name: Test Cluster
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 []  INFO: Package Manager: aptitude
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Recognizing new node 127.0.0.1 ('-8867774524416669848')
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Keyspaces: {'system_traces': CassandraKeyspace(name=system_traces, column_families=[], tables=[u'events', u'sessions'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'OpsCenter': CassandraKeyspace(name=OpsCenter, column_families=['events_timeline', 'settings', 'rollups60', 'rollups86400', 'bestpractice_results', 'pdps', 'rollups7200', 'events', 'rollups300'], tables=[u'events_timeline', u'settings', u'rollups60', u'rollups86400', u'bestpractice_results', u'pdps', u'rollups7200', u'events', u'rollups300'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '1'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'system': CassandraKeyspace(name=system, column_families=['IndexInfo', 'NodeIdInfo', 'schema_keyspaces', 'hints'], tables=[u'peers', u'range_xfers', u'schema_keyspaces', u'schema_columns', u'IndexInfo', u'schema_triggers', u'sstable_activity', u'peer_events', u'paxos', u'batchlog', u'NodeIdInfo', u'compaction_history', u'compactions_in_progress', u'schema_columnfamilies', u'local', u'hints'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}), 'dse_system': CassandraKeyspace(name=dse_system, column_families=[], tables=[u'encrypted_keys', u'leases'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.EverywhereStrategy'})}
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Persisting agent configuration to Cassandra
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Initializing event storage.
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Attempting to load all persisted alert rules
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Done initializing event storage.
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Version: {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': u'4.5.2', 'cassandra': u'2.0.10.71'}
2014-10-20 19:40:13+0200 [local]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 changed its mode to normal
2014-10-20 19:40:15+0200 [local]  INFO: Using 127.0.0.1 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: Received SIGTERM, shutting down.
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 [local]  INFO: OpsCenter shutting down.
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 [local]  INFO: Stopping repair service
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: (TCP Port 61620 Closed)
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: (TCP Port 61619 Closed)
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: Stopping factory <morbid.morbid.StompFactory instance at 0x7fe237a41368>
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: (TCP Port 8888 Closed)
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: Stopping factory <opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer instance at 0x7fe23a2ac128>
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 [local]  INFO: Stopping CassandraCluster service
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 [local] ERROR: Error publishing event plugin "CassandraStore": Connection closed ([Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
    ])
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: Main loop terminated.
2014-10-20 19:40:44+0200 []  INFO: Server Shut Down.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Log opened.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: twistd 10.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.7 2.7.6) starting up.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: set uid/gid 0/0
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Logging level set to 'info'
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: OpsCenter version: 5.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Compatible agent version: 5.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Loading per-cluster config file ./conf/clusters/local.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: HTTP BASIC authentication disabled
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Starting webserver with ssl disabled.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Stats Reporter is connected via HTTP
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: SSL disabled
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [] ERROR: Unable to import SSL, further definition actions will fail.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Starting Definition Update Service
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer starting on 8888
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer instance at 0x7f681b6bd128>
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: morbid.morbid.StompFactory starting on 61619
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Starting factory <morbid.morbid.StompFactory instance at 0x7f6818e52368>
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Configuring agent communication with ssl support disabled.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: morbid.morbid.StompFactory starting on 61620
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [] ERROR: No http agent exists, likely due to SSL import failure.
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Starting services for cluster local
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugins
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf ./conf/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading event plugins
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Metric caching enabled with 50 points and 1000 metrics cached
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 []  INFO: Starting PushService
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: Starting CassandraCluster service
2014-10-20 19:40:45+0200 [local]  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra/system.log', 'thrift_port': 9160, 'jmx_pass': '*****', 'thrift_ssl_truststore': None, 'rollups86400_ttl': -1, 'api_port': '61621', 'use_ssl': 0, 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'kerberos_debug': False, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'thrift_user': '', 'provisioning': 0, 'metrics_ignored_column_families': '', 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter', 'jmx_user': '', 'cassandra_install_location': '', 'kerberos_use_keytab': True, 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'thrift_pass': '*****', 'metrics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'metrics_enabled': 1, 'kerberos_use_ticket_cache': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_type': 'JKS', 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'kerberos_renew_tgt': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_password': '*****'}
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 []  INFO: OS Version: Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 []  INFO: CPU Info: ['2666.774', '2666.774']
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 []  INFO: Mem Info: 2989MB
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Enterprise functionality: True
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Cluster Name: Test Cluster
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 []  INFO: Package Manager: aptitude
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Recognizing new node 127.0.0.1 ('-8867774524416669848')
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Keyspaces: {'system_traces': CassandraKeyspace(name=system_traces, column_families=[], tables=[u'events', u'sessions'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'OpsCenter': CassandraKeyspace(name=OpsCenter, column_families=['events_timeline', 'settings', 'rollups60', 'rollups86400', 'bestpractice_results', 'pdps', 'rollups7200', 'events', 'rollups300'], tables=[u'events_timeline', u'settings', u'rollups60', u'rollups86400', u'bestpractice_results', u'pdps', u'rollups7200', u'events', u'rollups300'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '1'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'system': CassandraKeyspace(name=system, column_families=['IndexInfo', 'NodeIdInfo', 'schema_keyspaces', 'hints'], tables=[u'peers', u'range_xfers', u'schema_keyspaces', u'schema_columns', u'IndexInfo', u'schema_triggers', u'sstable_activity', u'peer_events', u'paxos', u'batchlog', u'NodeIdInfo', u'compaction_history', u'compactions_in_progress', u'schema_columnfamilies', u'local', u'hints'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}), 'dse_system': CassandraKeyspace(name=dse_system, column_families=[], tables=[u'encrypted_keys', u'leases'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.EverywhereStrategy'})}
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Persisting agent configuration to Cassandra
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Initializing event storage.
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Attempting to load all persisted alert rules
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Done initializing event storage.
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Version: {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': u'4.5.2', 'cassandra': u'2.0.10.71'}
2014-10-20 19:40:46+0200 [local]  INFO: Node 127.0.0.1 changed its mode to normal
2014-10-20 19:40:48+0200 [local]  INFO: Using 127.0.0.1 as the RPC address for node 127.0.0.1
2014-10-20 19:40:59+0200 [local]  INFO: Agent for ip 127.0.0.1 is version u'5.0.1'
```

Comment: `2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 []  INFO: Loading per-cluster config file ./conf/clusters/local.conf` this line suggests you’re using a tarball install. In this case, opscenter uses a configuration file located in the install dir, not the `/etc/` one.

Comment: You are right. I have found the right configuration file in `/usr/share/opscenter/conf` directory. Thank you very much. An interesting thing is that the documentation says, when you use the installer and install it in service mode, then configuration goes to `/etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf`. I have definitely installed it as a service and it uses `install_location/conf/opscenterd.conf`.

Comment: Anyway, my problem is solved. Please submit it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2014-10-20 19:40:12+0200 [] INFO: Loading per-cluster config file ./conf/clusters/local.conf` this line suggests you’re using a tarball install. In this case, opscenter uses a configuration file located in the install dir, not the /etc/ one.